# Spatial Autocorrelation in R

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, autocorrelation, moran-index

I have a point pattern with which I would like to test for spatial autocorrelation (Moran's I). All of the examples I have seen test for autocorrelation for some variable `y`, however, since I just have the latitude and longitude and no other data other than the timestamp of these observations, how can I test for autocorrelation? Can I perhaps create a dummy variable with which I can run Moran's I?

Comment: Moran's I is a test for spatial correlation of measured values at locations by looking at the values in neighbouring spatial units. If you create a dummy variable then you'll get back whether your dummy variable is correlated spatially, which doesn't tell you anything about your data. Are you really after a test for *spatial clustering* - which refers to the locations of the points rather than any value associated with them?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I will look into spatial clustering.